# windows dvd maker encoding

Tags: windows-7, windows, dvd, burning

My Windows DVD Maker stops/freezes the encoding process on some movies that I have converted to AVI files. Is there an answer to this using Windows DVD Maker? Or is there another software product that is better? (using Windows 7 Professional)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running windows update?  Make sure you take a look at the optional updates.

You can try Handbrake or DVD Flick if you're trying to go AVI to playable DVD.  CDBurnerXP is typically for audio and data CDs/DVDs.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's better but you might try [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/):

> CDBurnerXP is a free application to burn CDs and DVDs, including
>   Blu-Ray and HD-DVDs. It also includes the feature to burn and create
>   ISOs, as well as a multilanguage interface. Everyone, even companies,
>   can use it for free. It does not include adware or similar malicious
>   components.

[image]